How to deactivate Jupyter Notebook popup (Add Code Cell, Add Markdown Cell) between cells and on last row
In PyCharm I added the standard Jupyter Notebook plugin and run my notebooks on PyCharm with it. Now I see the annoying popup between cells showing "Add Code Cell" & "Add Markdown Cell" whenever I hover underneath a notebook cell and in the last cell this pop up will show all the time.
Anyone know how I can remove it or disable it?
I mostly used standard plugins for PyCharm and have only one downloaded plugin (CoPilot).
I already found some explanations from JetBrains: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/editing-jupyter-notebook-files.html#working-with-notebook-cells . In the "Working with notebook cells" section the popup between the cells is also described and explained but I cant find anything on how to disable them.
Would greatly appreciate if anyone knows what to do. It's not a critical issue but kinda annoying.
